# How to download a list of `FastQ` files in `Nextflow` using `fromSRA` function?

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow

I have a `tsv` file with various columns. One of the columns of interest for me is the `run_accession` column. It contains accession id of various genome data samples. I want to write a pipeline in `Nextflow` which reads accession ids from this file using the following command:

`cut -f4 datalist.tsv | sed -n 2,11p`

Output:

```
ERR2512385  
ERR2512386  
ERR2512387  
ERR2512388  
ERR2512389  
ERR2512390  
ERR2512391  
ERR2512392  
ERR2512393  
ERR2512394
```

and feed this list of IDs into `Channel.fromSRA` method. So far, I have tried this:

```
#!/home/someuser/bin nextflow

nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.datalist = "$baseDir/datalist.tsv"

process fetchRunAccession {
    input:
    path dlist

    output:
    file accessions

    """
    cut -f4 $dlist | sed -n 2,11p
    """
}

process displayResult {
    input:
    file accessions

    output:
    stdout

    """
    echo "$accessions"
    """
}

workflow {
    accessions_p = fetchRunAccession(params.datalist)
    result = displayResult(accessions_p)
    result.view { it }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Error executing process > 'fetchRunAccession'

Caused by:
  Missing output file(s) `accessions` expected by process `fetchRunAccession
```

If I run just the first process it works well and prints 10 lines as expected. The second process is just a placeholder for the actual `fromSRA` implementation but I have not been able to use the output of first process as the input of second. I am very new to Nextflow and my code probably has some silly mistakes. I would appreciate any help in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [fromSRA](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/channel.html#fromsra) function is actually a factory method. It requires either a project/study id, or one or more accession numbers, which must be specified as a list. A channel emitting accession numbers (like in your example code) will not work here. Also, it would be better to avoid spawning a separate job/process just to parse a small CSV file. Instead, just let your main Nextflow process do this. There's lots of ways to do this, but for CSV input I find using Nextflow's [CsvSplitter](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/master/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/splitter/CsvSplitter.groovy) class makes this easy:

```
import nextflow.splitter.CsvSplitter

nextflow.enable.dsl=2


def fetchRunAccessions( tsv ) {

    def splitter = new CsvSplitter().options( header:true, sep:'\t' )
    def reader = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( tsv ) )

    splitter.parseHeader( reader )

    List<String> run_accessions = []
    Map<String,String> row

    while( row = splitter.fetchRecord( reader ) ) {

       run_accessions.add( row['run_accession'] )
    }

    return run_accessions
}


workflow {

    accessions = fetchRunAccessions( params.filereport )

    Channel
        .fromSRA( accessions )
        .view()
}
```

Note that Nextflow's ENA download URL was updated recently. You'll need the latest version of Nextflow ([21.07.0-edge](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/releases/tag/v21.07.0-edge)) to get this to run easily:

```
NXF_VER=21.07.0-edge nextflow run test.nf --filereport filereport.tsv
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Yes, it took me a while to figure out that I needed to use `edge` release to use `fromSRA`. You are also correct in stating that I do not need a dedicated process block just to read columns from a `csv`, thank you again for pointing that out. Your solution is exactly what I wanted to do. I was unaware that we could use `List` and `Map` from `Java`!